# Code working but should fail, is this a caching issue?

Tags: c#, sqlite, dbcontext

I have a C# app using an SQLite database which generated an exception:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: 'An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.'
>
> Inner Exception: SqliteException: SQLite Error 19: 'NOT NULL constraint failed: RefreshTokens.AccountId'.

I fixed the bug (in class derived from `DbContext`) by adding:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
                .HasMany(e => e.RefreshTokens)
                .WithOne(e => e.Account)
                .IsRequired();
}
```

I would like to reproduce the bug, so commented out the code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
    //             .HasMany(e => e.RefreshTokens)
    //             .WithOne(e => e.Account)
    //             .IsRequired();
}
```

But the code still works as if there was some sort of caching. What do I need to do for the bug to resurface?

Code to update database (method `getRefreshToken`):

```
private (RefreshToken, Account) getRefreshToken(string token)
{
    var account = _context.Accounts
                          .Include(x => x.RefreshTokens)
                          .SingleOrDefault(u => u.RefreshTokens.Any(t => t.Token == token));
        
    if (account == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception thrown");
        throw new AppException("Invalid token");
    }

    var refreshToken = account.RefreshTokens
                              .Single(x => x.Token == token);

    if (!refreshToken.IsActive) 
         throw new AppException("Invalid token");

    return (refreshToken, account);
}

public AuthenticateResponse RefreshToken(string token, string ipAddress)
{
    log.Info("RefreshToken before locking");
    Monitor.Enter(lockObject);

    using (IDbContextTransaction transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            var (refreshToken, account) = getRefreshToken(token);
                    
            _context.Update(account);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            transaction.Commit();

            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
            Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + "Error occurred.");
            log.Error("RefreshToken:" + ex.Message);
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
            log.Info("RefreshToken after locking");
        }
    }
}

namespace WebApi.Helpers
{
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
        public DbSet<SystemInfo> SystemInformation { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Schedule> Schedules { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Function> UserFunctions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SchedulePoolElement> SchedulePoolElements { get; set; }
        
        public DbSet<RefreshToken> RefreshTokens { get; set; }

        private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;

        public DataContext(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        {
            // connect to sqlite database
            options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebApiDatabase"));
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().HasMany(e => e.RefreshTokens).WithOne(e => e.Account).IsRequired();
        }
    }
}
```

`Account` class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WebApi.Entities
{
    public class Account
    { 
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public List<RefreshToken> RefreshTokens { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`RefreshToken` class:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WebApi.Entities
{
    [Owned]
    public class RefreshToken
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Account Account { get; set; }
        public string Token { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to provide more. First, does commenting out the line makes it the same before you added that line? What was the originally generated codes? Did you tried regenerate the data models again? Second, what's your code of updating the db?

Comment: 1) The code commented out is exactly the code that generated the exception (before the `OnModelCreating` method was empty)                                                                              2) I didn't try to regenerate the data models                                                                          3) I added code of updating the db in my original post

Comment: Did you persist your sqllite database somewhere, or it is always in-memory and deleted on exit (each time you tried the code, there is no data from older tries)?

Comment: I added to my original post the whole `DbContext` content. From that you can see I am persisting data in the local database `WebApiDatabase`

Comment: Its a very complicated answer - for a novice like me. Sorry I don't quite understand that. I am sure you are right. Is there anything I can change in my code to reproduce the exception?

Comment: Deleted my former comment because it's a wild guess. I think you need to provide the `account = ...` part, how did you update the entity exactly, and how did you queried the `Account` object. Too few info to analyze the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254357/discussion-between-janusz-dalecki-and-xiang-wei-huang).

Answer (score 0):

You created an relation between "Account" and "RefreshTokens" and your foreign key "AccountId" it is null, but your configuration for "AccountId" it is"IsRequired"

Try like this

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
                .HasMany(e => e.RefreshTokens)
                .WithOne(e => e.Account);
}
```

Comment: The existing code works. I am trying to re-create the code that triggers the exception. Even if I comment out the fix (content of the `OnModelCreating` method) the code still works.